# Из List в DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

Всем привет! Подскажите, как List, состоящий из String, перенести в определенную колонку DataGridView. С DataSource у меня не получилось, какие еще есть методы?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.90).aspx#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B для ответа не очень,но мб пригодится

Comment: @TEA Спасибо, нашла уже сама решение :)

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что все просто :)

```
for (int l = 0; l < optionList.Count; l++)
     {
          dataGridView2.Rows.Add(optionList[l],"");
     }
```